# Attic wiring for a chandelier

Tags: electrical, attic, wire

To wire a chandelier I have attached it to already installed ceiling recessed lights. I bought a Appliance Power Cord and attached to one of the ceiling lights and the plug to a female plug attached to wire from the chandelier. Can this create fire in attic? Also the dimmer for the ceiling lights gets hot if not fully open.

Comment: Can you post some photos? Sounds like you've kludged something together, that may be dangerous.

Comment: Is this fixture a plug connected or did you wire the plug. If it had the plug it should be listed , if you put a plug on a fixture ,, not code compliant , hope your fire insurance is up to date.